# How to automate backup of records before sandbox refresh?

Tags: sandbox-refresh

I want to automate the records backup process from Standard and custom objects before initiating sandbox refresh & reload it again once the refresh completed. kindly let me know the ways to automate this process.

Thanks in anticipation,
Karthik

Comment: Apart from Data loader I understand that we can use other tools like informatica Data wizard to backup and restore records. But i could not find option for automate it based on my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach could be using [Run Script After Sandbox Creation and Refresh](https://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_deployment_sandbox_postcopy_script.htm) feature from Spring 16 release. You could programatically define your default testing data and change it accordingly as your config & code changes.

It would be fairly hard, but would give you very precise control. I think mostly this feature is for disabling third party integrations, outbound messages and such after the refresh.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally suggest you to have a  scheduled job each week/month , that would upload all the sf backup data to dropbox/ box.com . For example you can export it as a webservice and make Dropbox api callouts. This link should provide you with the basic functionality how to access Dropbox api https://github.com/financialforcedev/ffhttp-dropbox?files=1

Answer (score 0):

Check belwo link may help you
https://gaganbansalblog4u.com/2013/08/11/cli-data-loader-through-command-prompt-salesforce/
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009u2XIAQ
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F00000008sSKIAY
http://forcecertified.com/2009/08/19/the-easy-way-command-line-data-loader-tips-tricks/